# populating and getting values from spinner based from sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

hi I am fairly new to adnroid dev and I have a function that need to have a dropdownlist / spinner. the spinner's data should be based from my sqlite database the values the user can see should be the text but the data i should be able to get is the id of that text. 
In my DBHelper class I have this code to get all the values inside my table. my table is Area.

**update**

```
//view areas
public Set<String> getAllData() {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    String selectQuery = "select * from area ";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            set.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return set;
}
```

and in my addLocation class here is how i use the spinner. i dont have much because im stuck already

**update**

here is my updated code for `onCreate` but still i can't see the data from my db in my spinner

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addplace);
    Spinner spn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.areas);

    ArrayList<String> my_array = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> set = db.getAllData();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(addLocation.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spn.setAdapter(adapter);

    spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
            String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

}
```

any ideas what i needed to do next? or point me to the right diraection? thanks so much for any help!

Comment: what is the property in `Area` object you want to display in `Spinner`

Comment: in my area table i only have `aid` the area id and `location` i needed to show the values of the `location` but the value i should get is the `aid`

Comment: where you store location store (in sqlite or ...) ?

Comment: im storing the location in sqlite db

Comment: so why when you dont get the `location` from sqlite like you get `aid` from sqlite then display it to spinner

Comment: try add `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

Comment: hi @PhanVănLinh i tried using that like this ` ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(addLocation.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` please see my updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117559/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-bourneshady).

Comment: You need to create pojo class for Area and then when you fetch data from sqlite return entire list of area class and use in drop down text and on select get the id from that class object